# Adding a dropshadow to the main <div> in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Trying to add shadow around the main `<div>` along with rounded borders at the bottom of it. I added the class with styling in the style.css already. But I went into firebug to find what `div` controls the "content", it was under the `<div id="main">`, how do I add the additional classes to that in the html code?

I know that the footer and header are just footer.php but how do I get into the other divs?

Comment: Provide some link to your website to check the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm not sure really sure what div your trying to control. Wordpress has a lot of their content sectioned off into different php files.  Such as `sidebar.php` or `footer.php` as you mentioned. It also changes depending on which Theme you use.

Usually my general method to edit `<divs>` in html I did not code myself is the good ole find and replace.  Use firebug or Chrome dev tools to find the exact name of your div, and then using the style.css or hard coding in the element style edit the div to your liking.

As far as shadows are concerned... For easy copy and paste and customization.. try something like this http://www.css3maker.com/

For example...

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000000;
```

Comment: Yes, that is the exact code that I added in the class for the shadow.